# How do I overwrite the signer in AWS Java sdk version 2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to migrate from aws sdk version 1.x to version 2.x

My code had the following snippet:

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();

ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
clientConfiguration.setSignerOverride(s3StorageConnection.getSignerType());

clientBuilder.withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build()
```

So now I'm trying to `setSignerOverride` with the new sdk. I've tried something like this:

```
ClientOverrideConfiguration overrideConfig =
                ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .putAdvancedOption(SdkAdvancedClientOption.SIGNER, signerType)
                        .build();
```

But `putAdvancedOption` needs the `signerType` to be of type `Signer` while mine is a `String`

Can I somehow convert `signerType` to a `Signer` object or is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Checking this one for you with the team.

Comment: Team said to log that in Java V2 Github here -- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2

Comment: @smac2020 what do you mean by 'log in Java V2' ?

Comment: They said they are not aware of this functionality. So you can go to this Github link and  created a new issue.